# How to pass ILogger to Dialogs

Tags: botframework, ilogger

I am developing with BotFramework v4. I have MainDialog where ILogger is injected. I need to pass the ILogger value to other Dialogs that I am adding to my stack, and cannot figure out how to do it. I have written code below but it's not working as I need it to.

```cs
public class MainDialog
{
   public MainDialog(ILogger<MainDialog> logger)
   {
     AddDialog(new GettingToKnowYouDialog(logger));
   }
}
```

In the GettingToKnowYouDialog

```
public class GettingToKnowYouDialog
{
   readonly ILogger _logger;
   public GettingToKnowYouDialog(ILogger<MainDialog> logger)
   {
    _logger = logger;
    _logger.LogDebug("test"); 
   }
}
```

Anything that is logged in GettingToKnowYouDialog shows MyCompany.MyProject.MainDialog as logger, not MyCompany.MyProject.GettingToKnowYouDialog

Comment: So it seems I can register GettingToKnowYouDialog in startup, and then do dependency Injection. Not something I wanted to do but apparently no better option.

Comment: Does `public GettingToKnowYouDialog(ILogger<GettingToKnowYouDialog> logger)` not work?